# Returns the nth short word in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to write a program that returns the nth short word in an array.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Words
{
   /**
      Returns the nth short word (length <= 3) in an array.
      @param words an array of strings
      @param n an integer > 0
      @return the nth short word in words, or the empty string if there is
      no such word
   */
   public String nthShortWord(String[] words, int n)
   {

int nthShortWord = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
   if (words[i].length()<=3) nthShortWord++;
   if (nthShortWord==n) return nthShortWord[i];
}

   } 
}
```

It's not running correctly and saying that I need to return a value, but I already am.

Any/all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what happens if your array doesn't contain n short words?? You should still return something right??? So return a `null` or something after the loop.

Comment: that makes sense! I added return null after the loop but it's still not running correctly.

Comment: What's the error??? Also checkout Anand's answer.. You should return `words[i]` instead of `nthShortWord[i]`.

Comment: I changed the return to words[i] and everything is running as it should.  thank you for your time/help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues I see -

1. You are not returning empty string if the conditions are not met.
2. You are returning `nthShortWord[i]` ,this would be leading to a syntax error since `nthShortWord` is an integer and you cannot subscript them , you should be returning `words[i]` .

Code -

```
public String nthShortWord(String[] words, int n)
{

    int nthShortWord = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].length()<=3) nthShortWord++;
        if (nthShortWord==n) return words[i];
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: thank you! changing the return to words[i] solved the problem and the problem is not running correctly!

Comment: I apologize, the program is now* running correctly!

Comment: I did! I was just waiting for the time limit to be up.  thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return a String value in all possible execution paths and hence the error. You can do something like this:

```
public String nthShortWord(String[] words, int n)
{
int nthShortWord = 0;
String shortWord="notFound";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
   if (words[i].length()<=3) nthShortWord++;
   if (nthShortWord==n) {
     shortWord =nthShortWord[i];
     break;
   }
} 
return shortWord;
}
```

Also notice the `break` statement as you need to come out of loop when you find the first short word.